# Automatic login for Forms authenticated MVC app based on Windows username, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an asp.net mvc application using forms authentication i.e. users/passwords are in a database.  This application is used by several customers on their own servers and one would like their staff to be logged in automatically as per Intranet because apparently having to login would stop them from using it!?!

I am sure you can't mix both Windows and Forms authentication so my question is, is there anyway to identify the windows/ad username or anything else in anyway so I can authenticate them manually?  I don't need to actually authenticate them via windows I just need to somehow get information that will allow me to match them to the record in the database.

Comment: While this is definitely possible, you should provide us with what you've attempted so far. (a specific issue you are having with the gathering of their AD users for example)

Comment: Essentially if I turned on windows authentication, forms switched off so I could get the ad username but not use the membershipprovider. If I try to get the ad username without windows authentication it isn't available.

Comment: This is becoming a more common question recently, you need to build a custom provider and it is relatively complicated.

Comment: I already have a custom provider as the usernames/passwords originally came from a desktop system and encrypt/decrypt a particular way.

Comment: Do all your users have the same account name as their windows account?

Comment: No but there is a field that allows them to enter the AD username for matching it.

Comment: Basically the application has it's own set of users, security groups, permissions etc for use with the rest of the application

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this.
You will need to configure IIS to have Windows Authentication enabled.
If their AD account matches their identification for the web application(or just add a column for AD id in your forms authentication database), you can strip the domain from their username and then validate it against your authentication database.

I have an HR database that we use to keep track of employees and their titles, based on the data contained in this database we allow certain privileges throughout the application:

Our company is still on active directory 2003 so it was impossible to manage credentials without finding a creative solution.

Here is my code:
        //find out who the Active Directory user is
        var username = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name);

```
    // strip the domain
    username = Regex.Replace(username, "DOMAIN", "");
    username = Regex.Replace(username, "\\\\", "");


    var first_initial = username[0];
    var last_initial = username[1];
    //The Ative directory structure is [first initial firstname][first inital lastname][badge number]
    var EIN = Regex.Replace(username, "[^0-9]", "");//get the badge number so we can query the badging database


    // check the employee database to see if this AD account matches something 
    var query = "SELECT BadgeNumber, FirstName, LastName,  DEPT_NUM, DEPT, TITLE, Supervisor " +
                     "FROM TABLE_WITH EMPLOYEE INFORMATION " +
                     "WHERE LEFT(FirstName, 1) = '" + first_initial + "' AND LEFT(LastName, 1) = '" + last_initial + "' AND BadgeNumber = '" + EIN + "' AND STATUS = 'Active' ";
```

Comment: Enabling windows authentication loses forms authentication needed.  I can't swap one with the other unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. In which case, can you deploy the apps that use active directory and configure them differently? [bypass forms & use active directory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265870/Bypass-Forms-Authentication-to-Use-Active-Director)

Comment: No there is too much going on with the application to change it to work with windows authentication.  Plus with windows authentication they are basically already logged in by hitting the site, I want to avoid that.

Comment: hmmm... sorry mate; sounds like you're painted into a corner. I'll let you know if I think of something.

Comment: Use a separate windows authenticated app to create the forms cookie and redirect to the original application maybe?

Comment: ^^ I think you're on to something there! ... Let me know if it works as I think this will be useful for some of my applications.

Comment: Created it and it creates a cookie etc but on redirect still get login screen so not transferring for some reason. Any ideas?